# Flutter. Using Theme, how to change scroll offset color?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, scroll, colors

For beginning I am very sorry for my English. I am not a native speaker and additionally this is my first post in this language. I will be grateful for your understanding. 
Here is what I mean:

[image: my screenshot]

How to set scroll color other than this green in dark theme? I can't do this.

Below is my code:

```
 theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: Colors.pink,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
    textSelectionColor: Colors.pink,
    textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.pink[700],  

    textTheme: TextTheme(
      body1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),

  ),
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`accentColor property`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/accentColor.html) of [**`ThemeData class`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)

> The foreground color for widgets (knobs, text, overscroll edge effect, etc).

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        //Change your color here
        accentColor: Colors.blue,
        accentColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GlowingOverscrollIndicator will do the work for you as in the following code,

```
GlowingOverscrollIndicator(
              axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
              // the color you want to change in place of green
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Your_ListView_Widget,
)
```